# In set theory; How to show $|B_3 \cup (B_1\cap B_2)| = |B_1| + |B_2| +|B_3| - |B_1 \cup B_2|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am unable to solve this problem. Can anyone show me how to prove this above formula?

Comment: You can simply use Venn diagrams to verify it.

Comment: I need its proof...

Comment: Drawing the Venn diagram will help you find the proof! @MAJadoon

Comment: took it from a research paper. paper only has following info:
|B3 U (B1∩B2)| = |B3|+|B1∩B2| = |B1| + |B2| +|B3| - |B1UB2|

Comment: It's not necessarily true.

Comment: This was originally posted at http://stackoverflow.com/q/29385167/2336725

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any two sets $A$ and $B$, $|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B|$, easily verifiable by drawing a Venn diagram. We subtract $|A\cap B|$ because we double count that region.

Letting $A=B_3$, and $B=B_1\cap B_2$, we can apply the above formula.

That is, $|B_3 \cup(B_1 \cap B_2)| = |B_3| + \color{blue}{|B_1\cap B_2|} - |B_3 \cap B_1 \cap B_2|.$

Then $|B_3 \cup(B_1 \cap B_2)| = |B_3| + \color{blue}{|B_1| + |B_2| - |B_1\cup B_2|} - |B_3 \cap B_1 \cap B_2|.$

So the only time this holds is if $|B_3 \cap B_1 \cap B_2| = 0$.

Perhaps the research paper you were reading imposed this condition somewhere.

Comment: Thank you. But confusion is: How |B1∩B2| = |B1|+|B2|−|B1∪B2|?

Comment: @MA Jadoon Sorry for the delayed response, but it follows directly from the first identity $|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B|$. We just have to add $|A\cap B|$ and subtract $|A\cup B|$ from both sides.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false. Take $B_1=B_2=B_3=\{0\}$, then we have $$|B_3\cup\left(B_1\cap B_2\right)|=1,$$ but $$|B_1|+|B_2|+|B_3|-|B_1\cup B_2|=3-1=2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample: $B_1=B_2=B_3=B$ where $B$ is finite and non-empty. Then $|B|\neq2|B|$

Answer (score 0):

The right side=$|B_3|+|B_1\bigcap B_2|$ ,but the left is $|B_3|+|B_1\bigcap B_2|-|B_1\bigcap B_2 \bigcap B_3|$, there is a problem!

Comment: you are right but I am unable to find reason of this proof. It has been proved in a major paper with thousands of citations.

Comment: Can you find other information to conclude that $|B_1 \bigcap B_2 \bigcap B_3|=0$?

Comment: Yes its 0. It gives empty set

Comment: Yes, then it works. You can see the first answer, it has more details!

Comment: Thank you Bing but I am confused How |B1∩B2| = |B1|+|B2|−|B1∪B2|?